# SavedStateHandle in shared HILT viewmodel is always null

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, dagger-hilt

I have a shared Hilt ViewModel with a savedStateHandle in my constructor. I use the Android navigation component and pass the argument I need to the navigation method like so:

```
val direction = SomeFragmentDirections
       .actionFragmentAToFragmentB(
           someArg = foo
       )
findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

Now, in the receiving Fragment, when I use the Kotlin delegate `by viewModles()` everything works fine. But when I use `by activityViewModels()` the saveStateHandle is always null, however, as far as I have understood, this should still work? What is the issue here? How would you share such a viewModel, when you still want to use savedStateHandle?

Comment: I suspect this is a bug so I've opened a ticket on Google's Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246078919

Did you manage to find a workaround?